# Sharepoint online, enable rich text editor for a custom field

Tags: sharepoint-online, rich-text, spgridview

I've an APP with an input text item. It's possible to activate the rich text editor of sharepoint (365) to edit this field? And If i want to do the same thing into a grid?

Thanks!!